# Keycloak modify registration data

Tags: keycloak

I'am recently involved with a project evaluating Red Hat's Keycloak SSO, IDM, security  product. There are numerous programming examples, up to date for the current release 1.6.1, and some videos on YouTube  using some older release.
After setting a Keycloak realm, you can easily register and authenticate a user using Keycloak's own forms.
Does anyone knows how an application which is set to use a Keycloak realm, can allow the user to obtain and modify user registration data?

Answer (score 1):

Edited answer given comment below (thanks for the feedback). Here are two Keycloak admin APIs that are relevant to this question...

Get representation of the user:

```
GET /admin/realms/{realm}/users/{id}
```

Update the user:

```
PUT /admin/realms/{realm}/users/{id}
```

For more detail you can refer to Keycloak's [admin REST API](http://keycloak.github.io/docs/rest-api/index.html), particularly those related to the UserRepresentation object.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Have been there just before your answer. Have also to note that the examples in keycloak-examples*.zip which can be downloaded from [link](http://keycloak.jboss.org/keycloak/downloads) provides concrete use examples.